# form_for trying to access non-existent path_helper with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, form-for

In my "buy" subdomain, I have the following routes:

```
  constraints Subdomain::Buy do
    scope module: :buy do
      resources :users do
        resources :messages
      end
```

I am making the new message form using the following code:

```
<%= form_for [@user,@message] do |f| %>
```

with the controller action:

```
class Buy::MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @message = Buy::Message.new(receiver: @user, sender: current_user)
    render
  end
```

However the page throws the following exception:

```
undefined method `user_buy_messages_path'
```

---

When I check with `rake routes`, I get the following methods:

```
          user_messages GET    /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)                           buy/messages#index
                           POST   /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)                           buy/messages#create
          new_user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/new(.:format)                       buy/messages#new
         edit_user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/:id/edit(.:format)                  buy/messages#edit
              user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)                       buy/messages#show
                           PUT    /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)                       buy/messages#update
                           DELETE /users/:user_id/messages/:id(.:format)                       buy/messages#destroy
```

So the problem is, I am not sure why the subdomain 'buy' creeps in. `form_for` should use `user_messages_path` not `user_buy_messages_path`

---

*P.S.:*

Model:

```
class Buy::Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: '::User'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: '::User'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the url of your form_for by :url option

```
<%= form_for [@user,@message], :url => user_messages_path do |f| %>
```